# Package BuildConfig does not exist while building on jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, buildconfig

I'm using jenkins to build my Android app. My app makes use of HockeyApp for crashlogging. I have serveral buildTypes but I want to prevent crashes being logged on the buildType I use for development.

I solved it this way

```
if(!BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("develop")) {
    CrashManager.register(...);
}
```

However when building on Jenkins my build fails with this error

```
error: package BuildConfig does not exist
```

I have been using BuildConfig.DEBUG in my app without any problems so far. Any ideas what's causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins has no acces to this file. Ensure that you add the path to it.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the `import` statement for `BuildConfig` is missing or incorrect.

It should be `import <manifest package name>.BuildConfig;`

Answer (score 2):

On the top of your `MainActivity.java` file import `import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;` or `import com.<YourProjectPackageName>.BuildConfig;` and then inside your environment values put these two:

```
IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED=false
IS_HERMES_ENABLED=true
```

My current project is `react-native`, we are using a `.env` file, and I have put those two variables inside the `.env` file.